# Passing Arrays to a PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Guys I searched a lot on the web how calling a PostgreSQL function by passing a list as a parameter. My function is show below, It received a list of Long (ids), and It will execute the query. How do I call this function in JPA? passing a list of Long as a parameter? Please help, Is simple what I want, just call the function that receive a list of parameter, passing the parameters with JPA.

[Passing Arrays to a PostgreSQL function](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/passing-arrays-to-a-postgresql-plpgsql-function.html)

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fngetempresasfornecembemmaterial(bens_materias bigint[])
  RETURNS SETOF empresa AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE id IN (
        SELECT empresa_id FROM empresa_bens_materias
        WHERE bem_material_id = ANY(bens_materias)
    );
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

This is my test that I try to call the function passing a Array as parameter.

```
@Test
public void testGetEmpresaByCombineEdital() {
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM public.fngetempresasfornecembemmaterial(:ids)");
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(4);
        q.setParameter("ids", l.toArray());
        q.getResultList().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

And I get this console output too:

```
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        public.fngetempresasfornecembemmaterial(?)
2018-10-27 10:50:30.803  WARN 25969 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
2018-10-27 10:50:30.803 ERROR 25969 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: function public.fngetempresasfornecembemmaterial(bytea) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error ERROR: function public.fngetempresasfornecembemmaterial(bytea) does not exist 
the function is being passed **bytea** not bigint[]

SO the List you are creating of Integer, you should try create it for BigInteger or Long.

```
List<BigInteger> l = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
```